# Byte size of string in PHP

Tags: php, database, string

I have an encrypted image and before saving it I would like to know how much space it takes up. I can get the number of characters via `strlen($img)` or via `mb_strlen($img)` but I would like to get a number like `16KiB` (or `KB`).

I then save the string into a `MySQL` database in `blob` format, where I can see the size of it using PhpMyAdmin.

**EDIT**
If I use strlen to get the byte size of the string (which I want) I get a different value from the byte size displayed in my MySQL database (where the string is not saved as a char but as a blog, meaning binary). How can this be? And how can I find out how large the binary size will be when I save the string in the database.

I save the string simply with the MySQL command

`INSERT INTO table (content, bla) VALUES ($string, bla);`
(not fully correct but for example purpose – this works when correct)

Now when I look inside my database it displays me a size e.g 315 KB but when I take `$string` and do strlen on it, it returns something like 240000 (Not the same in bits as in KB)

I will investigate my self...

Comment: @CurtisMattoon No it's not, I would be happy if there was a solution. But this requires me to know the size of the file/string, but I want to find out the size itself.

Comment: OP's wish to mark as duplicate has been fulfilled ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does essentially the same thing as Dany's answer, but a little more compact.

```
function human_filesize($bytes, $decimals = 2) {
    $size = array('B','kB','MB','GB','TB','PB','EB','ZB','YB');
    $factor = floor((strlen($bytes) - 1) / 3);
    return sprintf("%.{$decimals}f", $bytes / pow(1024, $factor)) . @$size[$factor];
}

echo human_filesize(filesize($filename));
```

Source: http://jeffreysambells.com/2012/10/25/human-readable-filesize-php

Comment: I got it now, I did wrong conversion. I entered this and now it's the same as in the DB. Thanks.